# Audio start recording has stopped - not working

Tags: java, android

Even i tried all possible solutions that i find, couldnt solve the problem. I just want to make a guitar tuner. When i execute,getting this message; "my application has stopped". I think problem is here "audio.startRecording();" when i remove this lane i dont get stopped message. I tried api 15,25 versions for my app and virtual device even my phone. Can u help me guys what is the problem?

Here is my code:

```
package com.xxx.myapplication;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int sampleRate = 44100;
    private AudioRecord audio;
    private int bufferSize;
    private double lastLevel = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        bufferSize = AudioRecord
                .getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        audio = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleRate,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);

        audio.startRecording();
        short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];
        int bufferReadResult = audio.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xxx.myapplication" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please add the logcat of the error you get.

Comment: here uploaded http://i.hizliresim.com/yEp1Ry.png sorry about that im new for android

Comment: any solution guys?